# How to apply thickness XYZ to this spiral not a

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have used the *screw* modifier to create a spiral, but after finishing and applying the modifier, I realize that I did *something*, and now my spiral is only a line. There was a question recently closed that sounds like this, but *I* am asking if there is a way to apply something like a lattice to it to make a 3D mesh from it. This is what I am trying to fix:[image]
File here:[image]

Comment: Hello :). Why not just convert it to a curve and apply a bevel?

Comment: When I tried that it disappeared.

Comment: Weird. Works fine for me, just tried it. If all else fails, you can [share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and I'll try to replicate it.

Comment: I am not sure if this would work, but my brain tells me you could just:
1) Select all the vertices
2) Extrude along y, type in small number (like .01 or however thick you want), press enter
3) Extrude & scale along shift+y, type in another small number, press enter
4) Extrude along y, type in same small number but negative
5) Extrude  & scale along shift+y, type in same small number but negative
6) Remove doubles

If it works I can post as answer, or if you would be willing to upload blend file that'd be great ;)

Comment: Why was this question closed? It has nothing to do with the other one.

Comment: The other question answers increasing the thickness of a *curve*, I can't convert my object to a curve.

Comment: Apply Scale and Rotation (make that a habit). Then add a solidify modifier.

Comment: Sorry that your question got closed... I checked out your .blend file, I have the solution. Essentially the issue is that you have too many vertices on top of each other. Assuming you are using blender 2.8 or higher (if not use remove doubles), go into edit mode on the spiral, select them all, and then press Alt+M and select distance on the pop-up menu. Type .01 in the Merge Distance field. Now you should be able to convert the mesh into a curve

Comment: Could you post this as an answer ?

Comment: You can't post answers on a closed question.

Comment: I tried the solidify and it worked!! Thank you @cegaton